# POST Parameter With Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

hi this is Model of Parameter to POST server :

```
{"SOSApplicant":{"Vehicles":[{"CarModelID":3299,"ChassisNO":"","Color":"قرمز","VehiclePlateP1":"22","VehiclePlateP2":"الف","VehiclePlateP3":"222","VehiclePlateP4":"22"}],"FirstName":"سینا","LastName":"اکبربان"},"PendingToken":"77398284-dec1-4472-a940-eeb564398d6d"}
```

I use Alamofire to send post and creat this parameter in `let ParamToSend:Parameters = ["SOSApplicant":["FirstName":"\(self.FName)",
            "LastName":"\(self.LName)","Vehicles":["CarModelID":self.ModelId,"ChassisNO":"\(chasisTextField.text!)","Color":"\(self.carColorTextField.text!)","VehiclePlateP1":"\(firstPelakTextField.text!)","VehiclePlateP2":"\(secondPelakTextField.text!)","VehiclePlateP3":"\(thirdPelakTextField.text!)","VehiclePlateP4":"\(fourthPelakTextField.text!)"]] ,"PendingToken":"\(token)"]`
but the server send me Error 400 
how to creat this parameter??

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong if we don't know how your server validates the request.

Comment: You can use a proxy to confirm whether you are sending the correct request. Something like https://mitmproxy.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is expecting an array of `Vehicles` and you are passing a single Vehicle dictionary.

Try this.

```
let ParamToSend:Parameters = ["SOSApplicant":["FirstName":"\(self.FName)", "LastName":"\(self.LName)",
"Vehicles":[
    ["CarModelID":self.ModelId,"ChassisNO":"\(chasisTextField.text!)","Color":"\(self.carColorTextField.text!)","VehiclePlateP1":"\(firstPelakTextField.text!)","VehiclePlateP2":"\(secondPelakTextField.text!)","VehiclePlateP3":"\(thirdPelakTextField.text!)","VehiclePlateP4":"\(fourthPelakTextField.text!)"]
]] ,"PendingToken":"\(token)"]
```